# The volume of a solid bounded by two cylinders and two cones.

Tags: definite-integrals, volume, spherical-coordinates, cylindrical-coordinates

Is it possible to calculate the following with a triple integral, and if so, how?

The volume of a solid bounded by two cylinders: radius = 1 and radius = 2, AND by two cones: $\varphi$ = $\pi$/6 and $\varphi$ = $\pi$/3.

I don't believe it's possible using only spherical coordinates or only cylindrical coordinates, for the following reason: (it wouldn't allow me to post the image directly as this is my first post here).

[2kreate.com/integral.png](http://2kreate.com/integral.png)

When you go to attempt to pick a range for $\varphi$ you will always have some unaccounted for volume as is represented by the (poorly drawn) image above.

Could you complete the integral by making a change in variables from spherical to cylindrical halfway through the formula? Or would you be stuck computing two separate triple integrals (the second being to account for the volume represented in the image above)?

Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said:

> When you go to attempt to pick a range for $\varphi$ you will always have some unaccounted for volume as is represented by the (poorly drawn) image above.

But we can try a trick. Since we have to find only the volume of the solid between cylinders and cones. We can find the volume in the first octant , then ***with the help of  symmetry*** , we'll be able to find the total volume.

Now , see the exact region drawn below...

[image]

I think every thing is clear now.

So,

$$V=8\times \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi /2}\int_{\varphi=\pi/6}^{\pi/3}\int_{\rho=\operatorname{cosec} \varphi}^{2 \operatorname{cosec} \varphi} \rho^2 \sin\varphi \  d\rho \,  d\varphi\,  d\theta $$

Hope this may helpful !

**EDIT:**

$r=1$ is the cylinder $x^2+y^2=1$ can be represented as $\rho=\operatorname{cosec}\varphi$ in spherical co-ordinate system.

Comment: Could explain a little bit more why the $r-$coordinate in spherical coordinates goes from $1$ to $2$? Thanks !

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2729478/516174 ,  see here!!

Comment: Ok i'll check it . I asked because i thought that $r$ must be depended from the angle $\phi$.

Comment: yes! you are right , there was a confusion between $r$ and $\rho$. Now it is clear.

Comment: Nice ! now we are getting the same result !

Comment: I don't understand your drawing on the left. What are the four blue thatched areas? Also, isn't the order of the integral ranges backwards? I do like your answer though.

Comment: @2kreate that thatched areas represent the region of our volume. And in some books,  the order of integral is decided by the limits i.e. we do integrate from right to left or simply by considering dependent & constant limits. Thanks!

Comment: Why are there four? Isn't it just be one solid ring around? Why go from 0-$\pi$/2 and multiply by 8 (and why not four?) rather than go from 0-2$\pi$? Is that just personal preference or is there a greater meaning?

Comment: no , it's a personal preference ,look if we have to find volume ,area or arc length , we can use symmetry because there are some less chance to do mistake . Actually , they are eight ( in every octant ) because cylinder and cones are below $z=0$ and above it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75918/discussion-between-prithiviraj-and-2kreate).

Answer (score 3):

I think is simpler to describe your region in cylindrical coordinates .

The cone with $\phi = \frac{\pi}{6} $ has equation $z = \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}$ and the other one $z = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$

So if we fix a point $(x,y)$ in the $xy$-plane and move straight up from that point we will 'hit' first the cone with $\phi = \dfrac{\pi}{3}$ and then the cone with $\phi = \dfrac{\pi}{6}.$ So our $z$ coordinate must be all the time between 
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)}.$$

So we are done with $z-$coordinate.

Now the bounds for $(x,y)$ must be between the two circles of radius 1 and 2 , so $$1\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2.$$

So our region in cartesian coordinates must be 
$$W = \biggl\{(x,y,z) : 1\leq \sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq 2 \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\sqrt{x^2+y^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{3(x^2+y^2)} \biggr\}.$$

Now converting in cylindrical coordinates our regions becomes

$$W = \biggl\{(r,\theta,z) : 1\leq r \leq 2 \ , 0\leq \theta \leq 2\pi \text{ and } \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}r \leq z \leq \sqrt{3}r \biggr\}.$$

So your integral must be

$$\mathcal{V}(W) =  \int_{\theta = 0}^{2\pi}\int_{r=1}^{2}\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}r}^{\sqrt{3}r} r \  dz\,  dr\,  d \theta$$

Ps.The result must be $2\times\mathcal{V}(W)$  since the region W is for $z>0$ but because the whole region is symmetrical to the $xy-$plane the case $z<0$ gives also volume equal to $\mathcal{V}(W).$

Comment: Thanks ! i just noticed that i didnt involve the case $z<0$.So the result must be doubled !